# Trying to parse JSON data to put in another JSON url to parse more data

Tags: json, swift, urlsession

So here is the situtation, I am trying to parse JSON data from link 1, and put it in a url to parse JSON data from link 2. I have created two structs for this. The first struct is my collect (where my id that I have to use to parse the other JSON in the second link)

```
struct Collects: Codable {
    let collects: [Collect]
}

struct Collect: Codable {
    let productID: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case productID = "product_id"
    }
}
```

my second struct that has the products (that will be parsed from the second link

```
struct Products: Codable {
    let products: [Product]
}

struct Product: Codable {
    let title: String
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title
    }
}
```

The title in the Product struct is the name of the product. In my view controller, I have the two following functions that are used to get the JSON:

```
func fetchJSON(url: String, completion: @escaping (Collects?, Error?) -> Void) {
    guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }

let session = URLSession.shared
let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    if let error = error {
        completion(nil, error)
        print("Unable to fetch data", error)
    }
    guard let data = data else { return }
    do {
        let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Collects.self, from: data)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(response, nil)
        }
    } catch let jsonError{
        print("Unable to decode: ", jsonError)
    }
}
dataTask.resume()
}
```

and

```
func fetchProducts(url: String, completion: @escaping (Products?, Error?) -> Void) {
    guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }

let session = URLSession.shared
let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    if let error = error {
        completion(nil, error)
        print("Unable to fetch data", error)
    }
    guard let data = data else { return }
    do {
        let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Products.self, from: data)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(response, nil)
        }
    } catch let jsonError{
        print("Unable to decode: ", jsonError)
    }
}
dataTask.resume()
 }
```

Where the first one is to parse the id's and the second one is used to parse the products. In my viewDidLoad, I am using this information to get the data and set it so the products can be put into a collection view.

In my viewDidLoad I have the following

```
let jsonURL = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx"


//We need to first fetch the collects
fetchJSON(url: jsonURL) { (response, error) in
    guard let item = response?.collects else { return }
    self.collects = item
    for i in self.collects {
        //This will put all the id's together
        self.collectionCollects.append(",")
        self.collectionCollects.append(String(i.productID))
    }
    //This will remove the first comma in the string
    self.collectionCollects.remove(at: self.collectionCollects.startIndex)

    //This is the productURL that we will use to retrieve the products and put them in the collectionView
    let productURL = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx\(self.collectionCollects)&page"

    self.fetchProducts(url: productURL, completion: { (response, error) in
        guard let item = response?.products else {return}
        self.products = item
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        //The products get printed here
        print(self.products)
    }
  )
}
```

To explain the top a bit, the JSONUrl is the first url to the JSON data, that is passed into the function to get the information. In the first for loop, what I am doing is taking the id's and putting them in a string and seperating them by commas, then deleting the first comma. After that, I call the second JSON function to use the new URL to get the products of the second URL. In the statement "print(self.products)" I get the product list that I expect and even if I do a for loop in the self.fetchProducts to itterate through and print out the products, I get the expected result. However when I try to set up my collection view with the data, its just a white screen with no information. I assume that the issue is in how I set this up and not the configuration of my cell.

One thing I forgot to mention is that in my view controller I have the following arrays:

```
var collects = [Collect]()
var collectionCollects = ""
//This will have the products
var products = [Product]()
```

I am really stuck, I am not sure if its best to do all of this in one view controller or split it up but it has to be one view.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is on collection views. I recommend taking a look [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/9334-uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started). If when you iterate you get the correct response then it is setting up the collection view that is your problem.

Comment: So I was able to get somewhere, I forgot to add the "self.view.addSubview(collectionView)" in my view did load and provide the collectionView with some constraints but now I get a casting error "Could not cast value of type 'OmarJSON.CustomCollectionViewCell' (0x104b7e2d0) to 'OmarJSON.ProductCollectionViewCell' (0x104b7e240).
2019-01-12 00:00:31.587722-0500 OmarJSON[24971:5540997] Could not cast value of type 'OmarJSON.CustomCollectionViewCell' (0x104b7e2d0) to 'OmarJSON.ProductCollectionViewCell' (0x104b7e240)."